# Django File storage API

Tags: django

Where would I "normally" use this API?

In models, URLs, forms, views.py?

Where would I "normally" use the File class?

In models, URLs, forms, views.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use this API when you have to [work with files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/files/#managing-files). The most common scenarios involve views that allow users to upload/download files. Of course *when* you have to work with files is something you should answer based on your requirements.

Comment: The link is outdated :/ was this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/ your reference ?